# download file from heptapod - curl or wget

Tags: curl, wget

With my install script for Tryton ERP, I need to download files from heptapod.net. As on my target servers git normally is not needed, I should use standard tools like wget or curl.

Could somebody explain how to achieve this - seems to be a little tricky, I could not make gitlab syntax work.

Thanks a lot in advance, Wolf

Comment: Alright - that was much easier than expected.
Just do a 

    wget "<path-copied-from-file-location>"

(right-click the download symbol)  
and you're done. The '?inline=false' at the end of the path name can be left away.

Comment: Please edit your question to add more context. We have no idea what this thing you are downloading is, nor what working example "gitlab syntax" you are working from. If you have solved the problem, consider adding an answer to your question rather than a comment.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not allowed to post an answer - so I wrote the answer as a comment.

Comment: Improving your questions may lead to up votes and reputation, which enables answering and  other benefits.